# WPF vs. Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms

#### Duplicate:

> - [WPF vs WinForms or Rich UI vs Stable Applications? What do you think about the future of the Windows Forms platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442667/wpf-vs-winforms-or-rich-ui-vs-stable-applications-what-do-you-think-about-the-fu)
> - [When is Winforms the correct choice vs. WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388711/when-is-winforms-the-correct-choice-vs-wpf)
> - [WPF versus Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms)
> - [Advantage of WPF app vs Winform for business apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636028/advantage-of-wpf-app-vs-winform-for-business-apps/636921)
> - [WPF, Winforms, or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504014/wpf-winforms-or-something-else)

---

What are the pros and cons of WPF compared to Windows Forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[We went to WPF and never looked back.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504014/wpf-winforms-or-something-else/504053#504053) At this point I recommend doing all new development in WPF because the experience is *that much better*. But take that with a grain of salt, especially if you have a team with alot of WinForms experience.

Answer (score 3):

WPF will require .NET 3.0 (or later) and will lend itself toward better seperation of your presentation / business logic / data access layers. If you have a UI Designer or you are proficent in Expression Blend WPF is probably the way to go.

If there is not a UI Designer and seperation of concerns is not an issue, WinForms will not introduce any additional learning curve to your project.

Comment: Separation of concerns should *always* be an issue...

Comment: Yes, but even with WinForms a high level of separation can be achieved, WPF just makes it easier to do the right thing ;)

Comment: I don't know about others but I've never come across a Blend UI Designer.  Just the regular dev's that dabble with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you work on a big project with (interface-)designers on the one and programmers on the other hand, WPF can be better than Forms as you can separate you GUI from your code much better through the xml.

But generally speaking I wouldn't see myself in a position to once and for all decide over WPF / Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, Visual Studio is going WPF as well.
[A New Look for Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2009/02/20/a-new-look-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx)