# Visual Studio - Windows Forms or WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

What are the differences between [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) and [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)? And does either give the programmer a greater advantage?

Comment: Winforms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms. WPF, [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx). Read these two first, understand them, then come back with specific questions (the differences between them are huge). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885266/wpf-vs-windows-forms) also has links to some of the many dupicates of this question.

Comment: The facts: WinForms came first.

Comment: why the downvote? not like he said something vulgar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A gist of the article *[WPF Vs. WinForms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/42636e55-a1e0-4b29-bbd1-cd8073585584)* from [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network):

**WPF**

> Pros:
>
> - Powerful styling and skinning structure
> - Easy to create an own look and feel
> - Does support Windows Forms
> - The future technology for developing Windows Vista Applications
> - The ability to reuse existing code
> - Highly advanced databinding possible
>
> Cons:
>
> - Declarative vs procedural code
> - Requires .NET Framework 3.0
> - Compared to Windows Forms, still in the development fase
> - Requires Dx9 compatible vidcard for advanced graphics

**Windows Forms**

> Pros:
>
> - Extensive documentation can be found on the Internet
> - Plenty of examples
> - Does support WPF
>
> Cons:
>
> - How long will this be supported? (I've read somewhere that Microsoft
>     is only developing WPF now, only maintenance for Windows Forms)
> - Design your own look and feel in an application is a lot of work.