# Which .net technology to select for desktop application?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, desktop-application

I need to develop a windows application where I have to do a lot of customizations like changing the size of form and its contents based on monitor's resolution. So, I need a lot of dynamic design changes here.

So, which would be better to go with .net winform application or a wpf application. I do have working knowledge on both environment; however, I am not very clear on deciding to choose which  technology.

The work seems to be workable in winform as well but what I want to know is which would be the best of these two for this particular requirement.

Please suggest.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/885266/1136211) why your question is likely getting closed very soon.

Comment: It is imposible to awnser your question without full knowlage of your requirements.

Comment: @peer The functionality of the application is not a problem but the main thing required is changing the design of the form at run time, with reference to monitor's resolution. Suppose there are extended monitors. So, I need to know which would be better for this requirement.

Comment: You can build the layout of the screen equally well in both UI technologies from the code. If you know each platform then its a simple matter of your preference.

Comment: @GeekOnDemand Windows Desktop or Windows 8 Metro, or... more requirements specified, more accurate is answer

Comment: @Regfor its a Windows desktop application which would support operating systems win xp onwards.

Comment: @GeekOnDemand Then when decide between technologies without 3rd party components, then WPF is only one choice for .NET. The same can be done with Windows Forms and 3rd party controls. But

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For changing the design of the form at run time, with reference to monitor's resolution fits better - WPF.

But when using Windows Forms, then you definitly need some UI Components. For dynamic layout in Windows Forms I've used DevExpress controls. But when speaking about technology itself then better will be WPF

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** recommend **WPF**. You have very much **settings** that you don't have in Windows Forms. I made Windows forms applications, but I like so much WPF.

In present **I make WPF applications**. You will be **happy** using WPF.